# PHP calculate next 5 values

Tags: php

[image]

In the picture you can see that I have a diagram. This is fed with values from a database.
On the right side you can see a menu that specifies what will come next.
These values are always added with a certain value. This is to make a prediction and tell what will happen next based on the values.

From the picture you can see that 4 values are read out.
These values are calculated with a minimum stock and a maximum stock. If the stock falls below the minimum it turns red, if you are in the green area everything is fine and the priority is on the red and orange values.
If e.g. " band 2 " was manufactured, + 4 is added. That means when predicting what comes next, these values should be calculated as well, so that an accurate prediction can take place. If all values are now in the green area, a prediction should be calculated on the basis of the smallest values including the addition at production.

How is it possible to calculate such a prediction with pure PHP?

EDIT:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e0RaIjIGnwqmtPapBucQyilEM588CUmAdD7ZbcA68X0/edit?usp=sharing

This is a google sheet, to explain what I looking for, hope this helps now to understand the logic what I mean.

Comment: “In the picture you can see…” honestly, I can see many things, only some of what you’ve described. There is a green bar, two yellow bars and a red bar. Of these, one is green, two are yellow and one is red. Further, two are Band 1, one is Band 2 and one is Band 3. Lastly, the right column has four Band 2 and one Band 3. I say all of this because you are expecting me to understand a problem visually, but without all the details. Instead, if you could focus on a dataset, no visuals, and provide an expected output we might be able to better help you.

Comment: For me. you need two function. The first function is to viewing(SHOW) to get the value from BE that will show in your FE so you can make the viewing accurately. Then the other function is just for trasaction(ADD). Also you have complicated data that can't figure even you show the code/value. It cannot judge the logic there.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Sorry, but can you explain me, where I didn't explained what I expecting or at least looking for? If you stoped reading after “In the picture you can see…” this part, then please read the other part too. There I explained as good as possible what i'm looking for.

Comment: The picture is a visualization of the problem, so it is an output. We need the input. I'm seeing something that appears to be the logic for coloring, but the they appear to be on a scale of 0 to 100, however provided are 9, 6, 4 and 4, so I don't understand how one maps to the other. Ignoring all visualizations, you should be able to give us a dataset and give us examples of what possible outputs would be, which should hopefully help us understand what you mean by "predict".

Comment: I added a Google Sheet, to explain it exactly. That's the best way I can explain it.